# What is the reason behind 'BanTransitiveDependencies failed'?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Recently I have added the [Ban Transitive Dependencies plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html) to my pom.xml as seen below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <banTransitiveDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- the rule will not fail even if it detects ignoredArtifact
                                 of group org.apache.maven, because it is excluded -->
                        </excludes>
                        <includes>
                        </includes>
                    </banTransitiveDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I try building my application with maven, I will get the following error:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BanTransitiveDependencies failed with message:

   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.2:test has transitive dependencies:
      commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:test
```

I am not sure I understand what is happening here. Why is the banning transitive dependencies failing?

By the way I have the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

So am I supposed to change the version of hamcrest-all? or should I add the commons-lang 2.6 to my pom.xml as well?

Could you please explain what is the right way to "ban transitive dependencies" ?

Comment: btw, are your about org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.2? version 1.2 [is not available](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all) apparently

Comment: @A.DiMatteo http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositories/ow2-legacy/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`banTransitiveDependencies`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html) rule is used to verify that your project doesn't inherit of an unwanted transitive dependencies. You configure it by:

- `<excludes>`: list of dependencies to ignore.
- `<includes>`: list of dependencies to consider. Those are exceptions to the `<excludes>` configuration.

By default, it excludes nothing, meaning that all transitive dependencies are banned by default. There is a slight difference between excluding nothing by default and including everything. The point is that you should define what you want to exclude in a global way and in that subset, define what you want to include.

This is why, in your example, the build fails: you have the default where nothing is excluded and you have a transitive dependency on `commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6`.

The example from the documentation explains that:

> ```
> <excludes>
>   <!-- the rule will not fail even if it detects ignoredArtifact
>      of group org.apache.maven, because it is excluded -->
>   <exclude>org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact</exclude>
>   <exclude>*:anotherIgnoredArtifact</exclude>
> </excludes>
> <includes>
>   <!-- override "org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact" to fail
>      if exactly 1.0 version of ignoreArtifact is detected
>      to be transitive dependency of the project -->
>   <include>org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact:[1.0]</include>
> </includes>
> ```

In this configuration, they want to ban version 1.0 of `org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact` as transitive.

So they redefine `<excludes>` so that all transitive dependencies matching `org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact` are excluded, i.e. all dependencies having a group id of `org.apache.maven` and artifact id of `ignoredArtifact` (which means all versions with those ids). Then, they redefine `<includes>` so that only version 1.0 of `org.apache.maven:ignoredArtifact` is banned.

Comment: so in my case, I should add commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 in include tags?

Comment: @KorayTugay Question is what do you want to ban? :) If you want to ban `commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6` then you need to have the same configuration as my answer but with those coordinates instead.

Comment: The thing I do not understand is, what other option do I have in this case except 2.6? I mean what can I want to ban except 2.6?

Comment: @KorayTugay It seems it's unclear to you what banning transitive dependencies is for. It is to prevent future developers to add a dependency in the POM unknowingly that it would pull in one of those banned dependencies. This helps to ensure that the build fails and prevent runtime errors with conficting versions of dependencies.

Comment: ah ok.. Yes you are right, it was unclear to me. So I ban commons-lang 2.6 because we already have commons lang 3. someone else comes and includes hamcrest 1.2 which will download lang 2.6, and because I banned it, the build will fail. so the dev will be forced to exclude the commons-lang as seen in Kolargol 's answer?

Comment: @KorayTugay Yep, exactly :).

Comment: I tought I was telling maven itself not to download 2.6 because 3 is already in my classpath.. Thanks for the clarification.. But my question still remains: hamcrest has dep to 2.6, and I go like "oh well I have 3, lets ban 2.6 and exclude it from hamcrest" but what if commons lang 3 is not good for hamcrest?

Comment: @KorayTugay Then you'll need to stick with 2.6 :) (and maybe ban 3). That's more of an issue of what version of commons-lang is hamcrest compatible with...

Comment: ah I see.. But I "know" I need commons lang 3, I need a method from that library.. so I can not ban 3.. Maybe I should just not ban any?

Answer (score 1):

The `BanTransitiveDependencies` rule will trigger whenever one of your dependencies' dependencies (i.e. transitive dependencies) are included in the build.

In order to avoid this warning, you'd have to exclude `commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6` when declaring your dependency on `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.2`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ah I see.. Clear answer, thank you. But what happens if hamcrest-all does not work properly with commons-lang 3.4?

Comment: @KorayTugay The question is, what do you want to ban? The right way, as explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36933426/1743880) is to exclude something to override the default that excludes nothing and include something in what was excluded.

Comment: @KorayTugay As @Tunaki said, it's up to you to decide which library you want.
If there is a particular dependency you want to avoid, the [banned dependencies rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) might be a better fit. For example, you're using the Spring Framework but don't want to have `commons-logging` because you're using slf4j instead.

Comment: @Tunaki I am not sure what I want to ban.. I know I need the commons-lang3 version 3.4.. Should I ban commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 ?